# Electric field at source points of any continuous charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, singularities

**In *classical electromagnetism*, is there a way to find the electric field at source points of a line, surface or volume charge? If there is a way, please explain in detail**

> **My idea:** I don't really know; but it seems to me we can proceed by making an infinitesimal $-$ linear, circular or spherical $-$ cavity and then find the electric field inside the cavity. By the way, I do not even have an approach to find the electric field inside the cavity we made.

Comment: What do you mean by "the electric field at source points"?

Comment: Electric field at points inside continuous charge distribution.

Comment: By continuous do you mean equal everywhere or just varying smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

The expression for the electric field of a point charge,

$$\vec{E}=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\hat{r}$$

can be extended to a continuous charge distribution divided into parcels with approximately constant density $\rho$ with volume $dV$ (as $dV\to 0$, $\rho$ becomes exactly constant):

$$\vec{E}=\frac{\rho\ dV}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\hat{r}$$

To get the total electric field at a point $\vec{r}$, we must add up the infinitesimal contributions from each parcel of continuous charge. This is accomplished using an integral:

$$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\int \frac{\rho(\vec{s})}{4\pi\epsilon_0 } \frac{\vec{r}-\vec{s}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|^3}\; d^3\vec{s}$$

Comment: What is $\vec{s}$ here?

Comment: The position of a particular point emitting electric field within the continuous charge distribution. When you integrate, $\vec{s}$ ranges over every point in the distribution (well, really, it ranges over all space, but these are the same because $\rho=0$ in the vacuum).

Comment: $\vec{s}$ ranges over every point in the distribution...Even at the point where $\vec{s}=\vec{r}$?? Won't it be a singularity.... I do not understand this. Please explain

Comment: Any idea of how to deal with singularity of line, surface or volume charges???